# How to get Tango documentation?

Tags: google-project-tango, arcore, tango

I am a Chinese developer and I am studying graduate school. There is a project in the lab that needs to use tango. Google shut down the official website of tango and closed the developer community and documentation， because I was just getting started and I am not familiar with Tango development. This has caused our project to be interrupted. So now I am in need of Tango documentation.

Comment: It'd be better if you could convince your lab instructor to allow usage of tango's successor ARCore by telling that tango is deprecated.
Check [here](https://www.blog.google/products/google-vr/announcing-arcore-10-and-new-updates-google-lens/) and [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/).

Comment: Because our project is for hand gesture recognition, the tutor think that tango's point cloud is very accurate, and he don't think arcore's accuracy is higher than tango, so I should developed it with tango.

Comment: If your tutor is certain that he wants students to use a discontinued project, perhaps he can provide the documentation?

Answer (score 5):

The Tango related materials were moved to google archive Github account. Here are the links:
https://github.com/googlearchive/tango-examples-unity
https://web.archive.org/web/20170714191228/https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/

Hope these help! And yeah, I agree with @halfer though, you should communicate with your adviser and let him/her know that Tango on which is no longer a wise choice to continue working.

Speaking of hand gesture recognition you can consider Intel's RealSense Camera and its SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me very much! Thank you! On behalf of the Chinese developers, I would like to express my sincere thanks to you!